# Can we use Two separate xib's for iPhone & iPad for one viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, xib

I created two separate xib's for iPhone & iPad. From iPad xib i gave reference outlet to the viewcontroller.

What i want is: I want to use those reference outlets for iPhone xib's.

Note: I don't want to use size classes.

```
@IBOutlet weak var zoomButton: UIButton!
var delegate: FlipsideViewControllerDelegate? = nil
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var sliderPlotStrip: F3PlotStrip!
@IBOutlet var scrollView2: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var sliderPlotStrip2: F3PlotStrip!

@IBOutlet var detailsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var analyzeButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Comment: If you have 2 XIB's then two IBOutlet connections will be present.

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder i don't want to create  separate reference outlets for each xib's. Is there any way ?

Comment: If you have 2 XIB's then you need to connect the 2 outlets otherwise with one storyboard use sized classes

Comment: You can do something like this (2 XIB with single class - assuming XIBs have mostly similar items - attached twice to both XIBs - 1 outlet in class attached to both XIBs)     
    if (iphone) {
        [[ClassA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassA~iphone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        [[ClassA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassA~iad" bundle:nil];
    }

Answer (score 5):

Just create below structure.

- ViewController.swift
- ViewController.xib
- ViewController~ipad.xib

There will be no need to identify at run time to which xib to load.

By using ~ipad it will recognize automatically.

**What i want is: I want to use those reference outlets for iPhone xib's.**

Just copy that view controller from iPad xib and put it in iPhone xib

Keep size to "Freedom"

[image]

Now you would be able to resize UI components and all outlets would be in same.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the file owner from iPhone xib's to your class in Interface Builder. Then drag reference to your outlet.
At runtime, you can choose which xib to load.

UPDATED:
Swift code:

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
case .Phone:
    // It's an iPhone
case .Pad:
    // It's an iPad
case .Unspecified:
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, on Xcode 10, iOS 12, Swift 4:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DetailsViewController", owner: self, options: nil)
    } else {
        guard let iPadXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DetailsViewController~iPad", owner: self, options: nil) else { return }
        self.view.addSubview((iPadXib[0] as! UIView))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea it is doable, as long as you are loading the xib based on the device.

i.e., handle the nib loading via code.

**Solution in Swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var deviceLabel : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        loadFromNib()
    }

    func loadFromNib() {

        //Detecting Xib name by device model
        let nib = (UIDevice.currentDevice().model == "iPad") ? "iPad" : "iPhone"

        //Loading the nib
        let v: UIView = UINib(nibName: nib, bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        //Adding the loaded nib to viewcontroller's subview
        view.addSubview(v)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom() == .Phone {
    // If iPhone 5 or new iPod Touch
    if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
        var myViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerExt", bundle: nil)
    } else {
        // Regular iPhone
        var myViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    }
    // If iPad
}
else {
    var myViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerPad", bundle: nil)
}
```

Drag references of your outlet for `iPhone` or `iPad` `.xib`. No need to create separate `IBOutlet` just create one and bind it to both `.xib`

Answer (score 0):

I Implemented these logic before view load. Swift code is here:

```
   if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
                let controller = FlipsideViewController(nibName: "FlipsideViewController_iPhone", bundle: nil)
     self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
            }
            else
            {
                let controller = FlipsideViewController(nibName: "FlipsideViewController", bundle: nil)
     self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

I assume you have following files...

`ViewController.h
ViewController.m
ViewController-iPad.xib // For iPad
ViewController-iPhone.xib // For iPhone`

Add following micro

```
#define IS_IPHONE   (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 0 : 1)
#define LOAD_XIB(xibName) (IS_IPHONE ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-iPhone",xibName] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-iPad",xibName])
```

`*IS_IPHONE - Check if device is iPhone or not
 *LOAD_XIB - this micro use for load xib`

First Way --> you can use `LOAD_XIB()` micro like this...

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:Load_Xib(@"ViewController") owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Second Way --> you can also load nib like this...

```
if(IS_IPHONE)
{
   [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ViewController-iPhone" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
else
{
   [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ViewController-iPad" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: In the question, do you see any `objective-c` tag?

Comment: Sorry but i just provide some better things... language doesn't matter. logic and flow should be matter.